# match non-greedy regex delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have text where some of the text is delimited by:

```
{# xxx #} some text {# zzz #}
```

I have many occurrences of this pattern throughout my text. I'd like to extract the `some text` from the delimiters. How can I do this with a regex?

For example if I have this text:

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled {# xxx #} it to make {# zzz #} a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s {# xxx #} with {# zzz #} the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with {# xxx #} desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker {# zzz #} including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

I'd like to get a list like:

```
[it to make, with, desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker]
```

Here's my non-working code:

`>>> regex = re.compile(r'{# xxx #}.*({# zzz #}).*?')`

`>>> re.findall(regex, s) {# zzz #}`

I think my difficulties are trying to craft the regex in a non-greedy manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get non-greedy behavior simply by adding `?` in between the delimiters.  Also, you should not have `.*?` at the end. It doesn't do anything. `{}` are special characters and should probably be escaped.  Finally, the parentheses need to be around the part you want to match. That gives you this pattern:

```
 regex = re.compile(r'\{# xxx #\}(.*?)\{# zzz #\}')
```

To use it, you need a loop that uses something like `m = re.match`, then uses `m.group(1)` to get the first subgroup (the part in parentheses).  You need to use a loop rather than `findall` because you can only get the last match for a subgroup.

Comment: Wow, that's incredible! Why arn't the `{# xxx #}` and `{# zzz #}` included in the resulting match?

Comment: @turtle, see the updated explanation about using it to get subgroups.