# Using regex to find a string starting with /team/ and ending with /Euro_2012

Tags: python, regex

Hi simple question...

I want to find all strings that basically match the following pattern:

```
/team/*/Euro_2012
```

So it should find:

```
/team/Croatia/Euro_2012
/team/Netherlands/Euro_2012
```

But not:

```
/team/Netherlands/WC2014
```

How do I write this in Regex for Python using `re.compile`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15293234/677122).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
re.findall(r'/team/.*?/Euro_2012', inputtext)
```

You *may* want to limit the permissible characters between `/team/` and `/Euro_2012` to reduce the chances of false positives in larger text:

```
re.findall(r'/team/[\w\d%.~+-/]*?/Euro_2012', inputtext)
```

which only allows for [valid URI characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters).

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... /team/Croatia/Euro_2012
... /team/Netherlands/Euro_2012
... /team/Netherlands/WC2014
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'/team/.*?/Euro_2012', sample)
['/team/Croatia/Euro_2012', '/team/Netherlands/Euro_2012']
>>> re.findall(r'/team/[\w\d%.~+-/]*?/Euro_2012', sample)
['/team/Croatia/Euro_2012', '/team/Netherlands/Euro_2012']
```